# What is the joint density function of$ X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am supposed to give the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$, where $X \sim UNI[0,1]$ and $(Y|X=x)\sim UNI[0, x]$. I think it might be easier to give it's joint distribution function and try to derive it. I will denote $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$ the set bounded by $x\geq 0, \ x\leq 1, \ y\leq x, \ y\geq 0$.

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y\ | \ X=x)=\frac{y}{x},$$
if $(x,y)\in A$, and is $0$ otherwise. But I need $F(x,y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y,\ X\leq x)$.
Can you help me pls? Thanks!

(Also, I am not sure if this is legal in math.stackexchange, but if you could recommend me a book available online or a website, that has exercises like this solved, I would really appreciate it!)

Comment: If $p_X(x)$ is the density function for $X$ and if $p_{Y|X}(y|x)$ is the conditional density function for $Y$ given that $X = x$, then the joint distribution function is the product, $p(x,y) = p_X(x) p_{Y|X}(y|x)$.

Comment: If we know $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ and $f_X(x)$, we can get the full joint distribution: $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)$. Have a look here if confused - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Continuous_case

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers!

Comment: So then I have $F_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{y}{x}$ and $F_X(x)=x$, hence $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=y$. 
So my task is to find $f(x,y)$, such that $F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)=\int_0^{y_0} \int_0^{x_0} f(x,y)\, dy \, dx = y_0$?